# Set last n bits in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I wan't to set the last n bits of any given number to 1. I have a number (which is variable in it's lenght) and a variable n.

Example:

```
12 (dec) set last 2 bits
Output: 15
```

Now the basic operation should be something like:

```
return 0b11 | 12;
```

But how can I make 0b11 variable in length?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
int SetLastBits(int value,int numOfBits)
{
    return value | ((1<<numOfBits)-1);
}
```

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds! ;-)

Comment: @PaulR: Haha, yes I did. And the answers are more or less identical :)

Comment: And here you probably want an unsigned, not an int since shifting negative numbers isn't well defined :/

Comment: @tux3: he's only shifting the *mask*, so in this case it doesn't really matter whether `value` is signed or not.

Comment: @tux3: I'm shifting a positive number (1), and I'm shifting it **to the left**. What's not well defined in that other than shifting it more then 31 bits (which would yield an undefined result regardless of the sign)?

Comment: Nothing. But if you're shifting only positive numbers, why not take an unsigned instead of an int ?

Comment: @barakmanos: heh - you could make it `1U`, but it really makes no difference in this example - I think tux3 is just having a bad day.

Comment: Oh right I'm an idiot, I misread that. Disregard what I said. @PaulR I blame sleep deprivation :)

Comment: @PaulR: Somehow, when I wrote the answer, I had a feeling that it would circulate arguments about the size of the input value, its sign, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
uint32_t set_last_n_bits(uint32_t x, uint32_t bits)
{
    return x | ((1U << bits) - 1U);
}
```

This is also a relatively rare case where a macro might be justifiable, on the grounds that it would work with different integer types.

Comment: Why uintX_t instead of a simple unsigned ?
Especially since 32bit systems are getting less and less common.

Comment: And you beat *me* 24 seconds... I will go back to practicing faster typing :P

Comment: @tux3: well most 64 bit systems are LP64, where int is still 32 bits, but regardless of that it's usually a good idea to specify the size of an int type, rather than leaving it to fate. Feel free to adapt the example to your specific needs, of course.

Comment: I disagree, most of the time I want my variables to grow or shrink with whatever the target model is. When you do need to specify the exact size then yes, but simple arithmetic isn't one of those cases imo. You may run in performance issues with uintX_t.

Comment: @tux3: as I said, feel free to adapt the example to your needs - the purpose is to show how to set the last n bits rather than a philosophical exercise on the merits of fixed width versus indeterminate width ints.

Comment: Sure, I'm just nitpicking.

Comment: No problem - I can a be a bit of a pedant at times too - I think it goes with the territory when you're a software engineer. ;-)

Comment: change it to a template and then you can use whatever type you like :P

Comment: @paulm: if the question were tagged `C++` I surely would. ;-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity - how did you turn out to have less upvotes than the other two similar answers? I am giving you one to restore balance (ommmmmm)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the last n bits of a number to 1 in the following manner:

```
int num = 5; // number of bits to set to 1

int val = <some_value>;

val |= (1 << num) - 1;
```

Comment: 1 << 5 is 100000 minus 1 is 11111
Of course, shifting by n bits gives me one bit more than I need. Sometimes it can be so simple...

Comment: @kernelpanic it is not fair that you accept my answer. I was slower by 26 seconds and as can be seen by comments barak manos is the one to deserve accept.

Comment: Fixed that. Thank you all, anyways!

Answer (score 1):

As all others have showed the same approach I will show one more approach

```
int value;

//...

value |= ~( ~0u << n );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int set_bits( int x, size_t n )
{
    return x | ~( ~0u << n );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 12;

    printf( "%d\t%d\n", x,  set_bits( x, 2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
12  15
```

Comment: As I understand it, ~( 1 << n) should also work? Is there a bigger meaning to this fancy way of saying 1?

Comment: @kernelpanic No, it will not work correctly because all bits before 1 will be set also to 1.

Comment: So for n=5 mine would be 1...1011111 and yours would be 0...0000000, is this correct?

Comment: @kernelpanic For n = 5 expression 1 << n will give 00100000 and expression ~( 1<< 5 ) in turn will give 11011111. So you will get a wrong result.

Comment: @kernelpanic As for expression  ~( ~0u << 5 ); then ~0u is 11111111. ~0u << 5 will be 11100000. And at last ~( ~0u << 5 ) will be 00011111

Comment: Ah I see. Would you be so kind to explain why 1<<n results in 001(n*0) and not in 1(n*0)?

Comment: @kernelpanic Operator << shifts internal representation of an integer number left filling right poistions with zeroes. So if you have number 00000001 that is internal representation of 1 (I will consider onky 8 bits) then shifting it one position left results in 00000010

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense. I somehow overlooked that a number is always filled to system width/data type width. Thank you very much! I would like to give you an upvote for creativity but have not enough reputation.